# Why does this bisection algorithm fail to terminate?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, pascal

this is my listing :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  x1, x2, x3, xl, xr, xm, hasil, hasil2: Real;
begin
  xl := StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
  xr := StrToFloat(Edit2.Text);
  x1 := F1(xl);
  x2 := F1(xr);
  hasil := x1 * x2;
  if hasil > 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Try Again....!!!');
    Edit1.Clear;
    Edit2.Clear;
  end
  else
  begin
    i := 1;
    repeat
      xm := (xl + xr) / 2;
      x3 := F1(xm);
      hasil2 := x1 * x3;
      if hasil2 < 0 then
      begin
        xr := xm;
        x2 := x3;
      end
      else
      begin
        xl := xm;
        x1 := x3;
      end;
      ListBox1.Items.Add(FloatToStr(xm));
      i := i + 1;
    until
      x3 = 0;
  end;
end;
```

the listing is about BISECTION METHOD....
the problem is.....why the loop didn't stop...

anyone can help me...please

Comment: The reason is that `x3` never gets equal to zero. Maybe you could try `IsZero(x3)` instead, or `Abs(x3) < SomeEpsilon`.

Comment: ...or you could stop after `N` steps (e.g., 1 000 000) unless you reach some epsilon first.

Comment: Seldom any point doing more than 50  bisection iterations

Comment: thank you for the answer....but I'm really sorry...
i don't get it....

can you give the example :)

Comment: @David: Yeah, you're right. My example number was probably too big.

Comment: can I you explain about IsZero(x3) ?

Comment: @user2467583: IsZero is a function (found in Math.pas) that returns true iff the argument is *very close* to zero (but maybe not *exactly* zero).

Comment: How about SomeEpsilon ?

Comment: It is a small number, like 0.0001. (In mathematics, "epsilon" almost means "small number"...)

Comment: [`Math.IsZero`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Math.IsZero), `function IsZero(const A: Double; Epsilon: Double): Boolean;`.

Comment: I improved the question title. Things like that matter. Stated as it is now, it is clearer that this actually is a question. What's more, given that question statement you can immediately boil it down to, why does x3 never reach zero. At that point you have something to debug.

Comment: @andreas IsZero is liable to lead to non terminating loops also.

Answer (score 6):

Finite precision floating point arithmetic on a computer is imprecise. Not all numbers can be represented exactly and consequently arithmetic on a computer involves approximation. So it may be that your function has no exact solution on the computer. Or perhaps the solution exists but the approximation means it cannot be found.

Instead of testing for equality with zero, test for your value being close to zero.

```
until abs(x3) < 1.0e-6;
```

where the tolerance would have to be chosen according to some reasoned argument based on the problem at hand.

Another sensible stopping criterion for bisection is that xl and xr become very close. Exactly what approach is best for you depends on the function you are solving, and the properties you require of that solution.

Such issues are delicate.  If you use a tolerance then you might choose it too low. And then your loop will not terminate, a familiar situation. So you should always try to bail out after some large number of iterations. Unless you can prove for sure that the loop is certain to terminate.

---

Some advice on debugging. You already knew that the loop did not terminate. So clearly x3 did not ever reach zero. At that point you could have done some debugging and inspected the values of x3 and indeed the other variables. Had you done this I'm sure you would have understood the problem all by yourself. Learning how to debug problems is a critically important skill.

Comment: @JensG I quote: "... where the tolerance would have to be chosen according to some reasoned argument based on the problem at hand."

Comment: @user2467583 Do you need any more help?